# UIlabel's textaligment doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
    var customView : UIView = UIView()
    var a = screen_h/13+screen_h/30
    var b = screen_h-(screen_h/13+screen_h/30+1 + screen_h*0.8)
    customView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screen_w, (screen_h - a - b )/5)

    var headerLabel : UILabel = UILabel()

    headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    headerLabel.opaque = false
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    headerLabel.font = headerLabel.font.fontWithSize(30)
    headerLabel.textAlignment == NSTextAlignment.Right
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screen_w, (screen_h - a - b )/5)
    headerLabel.layer.borderWidth = 5
    headerLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    headerLabel.text = "My Header"; // i.e. array element

    customView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return customView
}
```

In this code, I want to let my UILabel text in the center, but text alignment doesn't work.

Comment: But you are using NSTextAlignment.Right,, why?
if you want centre then use NSTextAlignment.centre

Comment: also remove all the magic numbers, it seems you're trying to center the view, not the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've made a typo with the assignment operator and have the wrong text alignment assigned.

Change

```
headerLabel.textAlignment == NSTextAlignment.Right
```

to

```
headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```